# Calling model functions in a view in Laravel 4?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, models

I am using a function to write a query, and I am trying to return the variable the function returns and use it in a view.  In my model:

Fan.php

```
public function sample_query() {
        $count = User::where('fbid', '=', 421930)->count();

        return $count;

    }
```

In the view I am simply trying to call it with:

```
@sample_query();
```

This is not working.  I am new to this type of thing, and I suppose I don't know how to access  the data pulled by queries in the model in the view.  Please let me know if there is a better way, or why this isn't working.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your question it seems View Composer will solve your problem

View composers are callbacks or class methods that are called when a view is created. If you have data that you want bound to a given view each time that view is created throughout your application, a view composer can organize that code into a single location. Therefore, view composers may function like "view models" or "presenters".

```
View::composer('profile', function($view)
{
    $view->with('count', User::count());
});
```

for more info [read this](http://laravel.com/docs/responses#view-composers)

Answer (score 0):

starting from the supposition that you have a User class:

```
{{ User::sample_query() }}
```

Comment: I got this error:

[2013-07-07 02:06:22] log.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Undefined variable: fans' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/crowdsets/laravel-master/app/storage/views/c2d0eaffa48734ee7b6faba40228b7e6:93

I do have a table called 'fans'